# Delete Google analytics entries of leaked Personal Identifiable Information

Tags: google-analytics

we have entries in GA that appear with PII like so:

[image]

they are there because of a sub optimal way pardot implemented their form handlers. Basically on error the form handler will return a redirect with all inputs in query parameters. Those are then sent to GA. I have written a fix for this, but the old entries remain. Basically if I find error vars in the URL I just don't load GTM, and redirect to a save URL without PII.

How can I delete them?

yes, delete, not filter away. Because a filter just *hides* but doesn't delete.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First verify that you have found all PII and you're no longer collecting it. Then, create new views under your account where you will only collect this clean data. At this point, you should export everything you can, because once data is removed it won't be retrievable. Your data dump can contain the PII - that doesn't violate Google's terms, but may violate GDPR or other regulations, so use your best judgement as to whether your data dump needs to filter it all out as well.

Finally, you'll need to contact Google, let them know which views contain PII (and which do not). They are the only ones who can actually remove data. It is a good idea to go ahead and follow all of these steps - if they find the PII themselves they're likely to delete your whole account.

Some useful tips for locating all PII: http://www.cardinalpath.com/what-you-need-to-know-about-google-analytics-personally-identifiable-information/

Comment: but... the new views will be empty right. Can I then reimport the cleaned data?

Comment: Nope. That's why you need to do the export. But it's better than Google deleting your account suddenly when you have no export at all.